# order data based on an array

Tags: php, sorting

I have an array:

```
$order = array(2,0,1)
```

I also have three text variables

```
$a, $b, $c
```

they are each represented by a number $a is 0, $b is 1 and $c is 2

I want to add the variables to a text variable ($holder) in the order set by the array

so if the array is (2,0,1) then

```
$holder = $c.$a.$b
```

When $order changes I want the order in $holder to change to match.

I can make this work but it seems a really rubbish way of doing it so I wondered if anyone had a better way:

```
$holder ="";
$order = array(2,0,1)

for($x=0;$x<count($holder);$x++){

switch ($order)

case 0:
$holder .= $a;
break;

case 1:
$holder .=$b;
break;

case 2:
$holder .=$c;
break;

}
```

thanks

Update

Thanks for the replies they really made me think about the best way to achieve the result.  My own solution might work but that's not enough the code needs to be good too.  I think it's important to produce good code not just okay code so thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably not the fastest, but using some of the `array_` functions.  This inverts the order to make the order values the keys, then uses `array_replace()` to take the values from the corresponding point in an array of the parameters.  Then just `implode()` the result...

```
$order = array(2,0,1);
$a="1";
$b="2";
$c="3";

echo implode(array_replace(array_flip($order), [ $a, $b, $c ]));
```

gives

```
312
```

Comment: I don't think I've ever used array_flip.  This is an excellent solution.  The only part I wonder about is the speed compared to the foreach solution.  I am tempted to use it though so I can use array_flip

Answer (score 2):

Normal array contains key starting from `0`. You can use that concept and assign your text variable to array based on their representation.

Like $a represent 0, so put its value to index `0` of array and so on.

Now you can easily access these values by accessing array index.

```
$a = 'X';
$b = 'Y';
$c = 'Z';

$arr = [$a, $b, $c]; 

$order = [2,0,1];

$text = '';
foreach($order as $key){
    $text .= $arr[$key];
}

echo $text;
Output:
ZXY
```

Comment: I like this solution a lot.  It's easy to understand and I think pretty quick.  I think the only reason I'll go for the array_flip method below is simply I've not used array_flip before! :)

Comment: Not an issue, btw accepted answer also include a good conect of replace and implode

Answer (score 2):

A short PHP 7.4+ solution, using `implode`, `array_map` and arrow functions:

```
$a = 'a';
$b = 'b';
$c = 'c';

$values = [$a, $b, $c];
$order = [2, 0, 1];

$holder = implode(array_map(fn($index) => $values[$index] ?? null, $order));  // "cab"
```

**[Demo](https://3v4l.org/dhuEc)**

Comment: thanks for this - sadly it needs to work with earlier versions of php!  But I do like the map idea something I'm not that familiar with.

Answer (score 0):

Another version, hope to match with your idea.

```
$order = array(1,0,2);
$var = array(
    0 => "a",
    1 => "b",
    2 => "c"
);
$holder = '';
foreach( $order as $item ){
    $holder .= $var[$item];
}
echo $holder;
```